# The dimension of the space of functions restricted to a finite set

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider all the functions $f:K^n\rightarrow K$ restricted to a finite set $E\subset K^n, f:E\rightarrow K$. Why is the dimension of this vector space $|E|$ over $K$? What would be the basis of this vector space?

Comment: What do you think it should be?

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? I don't fully understand what you're asking.

Comment: Each function is completely specified by the values $f(e)$ with $e \in E$. There are $|E|$ simple functions that can be defined and any $f$ can be expressed as a linear combination of these $|E|$ functions.